# flickering issue with UICollectionView when data source is updated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have investigated UICollectionView flickering issue on my application (collection of photo loading from remote source) back and forth whenever I had chance to research how exactly UICollectionView behaves. I thought UICollectionView reuses the cell it previously used at same location (i.e. if a photo was loaded at row:0 section:0, and then `[collectionView reloadData]` is called, then the cell that was previously used at location row:0 section:0 is reused for the location. If so, because image at that location is already visible and it shouldn't bother to re-render at the same location. But when I looked into it closely, I found that UICollectionView picked a cell has different memory address than it previously used. And I believe it causes flickering affect when `[collectionView reloadData]` happens. I thought cell object memory address should be matched if UICollectionView reuses same object that it used before at the location. Is my understanding about UICollectionView correct? if not, I'd appreciate any advices. Thanks!

Comment: Hey were you able to  resolve this issue? I have same issue with my app too.

Comment: not really, but you can optimize binding method to use threads when loading image, text etc or if you use code to create collectionView, you can try to use the library from Facebook called asyncdisplaykit

Answer (score -1):

solved such a problem with putting

`collectionView?.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)`

right after

```
collectionView?.reloadData()
```

thus collection view updated synchronously with no flickering